# How do I autopopulate a field in Collector?

Tags: arcgis-collector

I am wondering how I can use location to automatically generate a field in my attribute table with the name of a geographic region.

I want to:

- create a point on the Collector app
- automatically populate the field for geographic region (polygon) that the point lies in.

Basically, how do I avoid having to do post processing on my attribute table using a spatial join?

My GIS experience is fairly limited...

Comment: Your options depend on your environment.  AGOL? Portal? Is your data in an SDE feature class? datastore?